# Can't get setScrollVisible() to work

Tags: android, codenameone

I can‘t get the method setScrollVisible() to work. Here is my code:

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
for(int i = 0;  i < 25; i++) {
    hi.addComponent(new Label("Hello " + i));
}
hi.setScrollVisible(false);
hi.show();
```

It does not work in simulator nor does it work on my android phone (Galaxy Nexsus – Android 4.2.1). The scrollbar is still visable.

[image: Scrollbar still visable]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The scrollable container isn't the form it's the content pane so you can also use `hi.getContentPane().setScrollVisible(false)`. - Shai Almog

Thats how you do it.

Comment: I answered in a comment to Diamond so you will accept his answer. Answering and accepting your own questions doesn't gain you points. If you want to reward people for their effort you can accept their answers and you also get some points on your own as a result.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the form to be scrollable, call `hi.setScrollableY(false);`.

If you want to keep the scrolling and hide the scrollbar, you will need to style `Scroll` and `ScrollThumb` in you Gui Builder.

There may be a simpler solution than this, but this is what I always do.

Comment: I have added `Scroll` and `ScrollThumb` in the Gui Builder. Still the same result.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you should style it, set background transparency to 0, Border Image to Empty and background image to none.

Comment: The scrollable container isn't the form it's the content pane so you can also use `hi.getContentPane().setScrollVisible(false)`.